# estimating sphericity

Tags: estimation, covariance-matrix, sphericity

I have $n$ independent samples from a $p$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance $\Sigma$. Optimally, the $p$ variables should uncorrelated and of equal variance ($\Sigma = \sigma^2 I_p$; white, spherical), and I want to check that assumption. I don't want to perform a hypothesis test, at least not primarily, but quantify the degree of sphericity.

If I knew the true covariance, this purpose would be fulfilled by the measure
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace} 
\epsilon = \frac{\tr(\Sigma)^2}{p \tr(\Sigma^2)}
= \frac{\left( \sum_i \Sigma_{ii} \right)^2}{p \sum_{ij} \Sigma_{ij}^2}
= \frac{\left( \sum_i \lambda_i \right)^2}{p \sum_i \lambda_i^2},
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. The measure takes on values between $0$ and $1$, and $1$ exactly if $\Sigma$ is spherical.

**First question:** I believe this measure is *Box's sphericity index*, however the formula usually cited involves division by $(p - 1)$, which I suppose is due to the repeated measures context. Is my formulation correct for the general case where I'm interested in the $p$ variables themselves, and not differences between them?

**Second question:** Is it possible to obtain an (approximately) unbiased estimator of $\epsilon$ based on the sample covariance matrix $\hat \Sigma$? I know there are different estimators for the purpose of adjusting degrees of freedom in a rmANOVA, including the *Greenhouse–Geisser estimator* based on the sample eigenvalues. However, such a simple estimator is bound to be biased, underestimating sphericity. This bias should be severe for $p$ close to $n$.

**Third question:** Is it possible to obtain a confidence interval for $\epsilon$? In particular, is it possible to invert *Mauchly's test* for this purpose?